# Get the previous columns of certain columns names

Tags: python, csv

I do have a csv file like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LJUs.png)

Which include duplicated names. The point is that i am only interested on speed and status.

so i defiend the following:

```
used_columns=['time.2','speed','time.4','status']

df =pd.read_csv(path,usecols=used_columns)
```

The tricky part is that if one of the columns is missing then it wont be able to find one of the columns (i have a lot of csv files and they might differ)

An option is to read the whole csv and save the column names and take to previous to `'speed', 'status'`, but im trying to avoid reading the whole csv since its a huge file and i have alot of csv files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use [`nrows=`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas-read-csv) parameter when reading the `.csv` file. That way you can read only few rows (and not whole file), save the column names and read only columns that are present in the file:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(path, nrows=2)

# columns are in df.columns:
print(df.columns)
```

Comment: Maybe thats the only way to do it. Thanks